# estimatedItemSize makes UICollectionViewCells hidden unexpectedly

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I just want to create a self resized `UICollectionView` whose cells have only one subview (multi lines `UILabel`).

I set the `minimumLineSpacing` property of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, it not only doesn't make my `UICollectionView` self-resized, but also make the cells hidden.

I don't know why, and here's some related codes.

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout* layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;
layout.minimumLineSpacing = MESSAGE_BOX_MINIMUM_LINE_SPACING;
layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSizeMake(MESSAGE_BOX_WIDTH, MESSAGE_BOX_CELL_ESTIMATED_HEIGHT);
self.messageBox = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero collectionViewLayout:layout];
[self addSubview:self.messageBox];
self.messageBox.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
self.messageBox.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
self.messageBox.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.messageBox registerClass:[ZhiboCameraViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:MESSAGE_BOX_CELL_IDENTIFIER];
```

.

```
@implementation ZhiboCameraViewCell
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (!self) return nil;
    self.label = [UILabel new];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.label];
    [self.label mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.edges.equalTo(self.contentView);
    }];
    self.label.numberOfLines = 0;   
    return self;
}
```

In Reveal App:

[image]

Comment: How do you know your cell is hidden? I think your cell's contentView frame is set to CGRectZero.

Comment: I use reveal app to inspect cells hidden property, and find all of them are checked. Images will be uploaded later. @nynohu

Comment: Try to change your cell's background color for surely it was hidden. In my opinion, I don't think cell will be hidden if you did not set it programmatically.